# Using SQL, how to get rows satisfying one of multiple conditions with additional boolean columns displaying which exact condition was satisfied

Tags: sql, relational-database

I would like to query a table for such cases that satisfy any of multiple conditions

```
... WHERE cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3
```

but i need to know exactly which of those conditions were satisfied.

I would like to get something like this

```
+-----+-                      -+-------+-------+-------+
| ID  | .. selected columns .. | cond1 | cond2 | cond3 |
+-----+-                      -+-------+-------+-------+
| id1 |                        | true  | false | false |
| id2 |                        | false | true  | true  |
| id3 |                        | false | true  | false |
| id4 |                        | true  | true  | false |
+-----+-                      -+-------+-------+-------+
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Use `case` expressions, or boolean expressions, in the select list.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either simply put the same conditions in the select list:

```
select id, cond1, cond2, cond3
from tablename
where cond1 or cond2 or cond3
```

Using ANSI SQL feature T031, "BOOLEAN data type".

Alternatively, use `case` expressions:

```
select id,
       case when cond1 then 'true' else 'false' end,
       case when cond2 then 'true' else 'false' end,
       case when cond3 then 'true' else 'false' end
from tablename
where cond1 or cond2 or cond3
```

Core ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `CASE`. I have prepared a sample, you can check it:

```
--DROP TABLE TmpTable
--GO
CREATE TABLE TmpTable
(
    ID INT
    ,   Column1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,   Column2 VARCHAR(100)
    ,   Column3 VARCHAR(100)
    ,   Column4 VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO TmpTable 
VALUES  
 (1,'AA','B','C','D')
,(2,'BB','A','C','B')
,(3,'CC','E','F','G')
,(4,'DD','F','G','H')
,(5,'EE','A','G','D');


SELECT   Id
        ,Column1
        ,Column2
        ,Column3
        ,Column4
        ,CASE WHEN Column2='G' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END Cond1Check
        ,CASE WHEN Column3='G' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END Cond2Check
        ,CASE WHEN Column4='G' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END Cond3Check

FROM TmpTable
WHERE (
               Column2='G' 
            OR Column3='G' 
            OR Column4='G'
       )
```

Comment: Does your dbms support `, Column2='G' Cond1Check` in the select list?